# R: Make new vector correlating to a specified level in a factor

Tags: r, vector, r-factor

I'm stuck with a really easy task and hope someone could help me with it..

I'd like to make a new (sub)vector from an existing vector, based on 1 level of a factor.
Example:

```
v = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
f = factor(rep(c("Drug","Placebo"),5))
```

I want to make a new vector from v, containing only "Drug" or "Placebo". Resulting in:

```
vDrug = 1,3,5,7,9   
vPlacebo = 2,4,6,8,10
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily subset `v` by `f`:

```
v[ f == "Drug" ]
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

However, this approach might become error prone in a more complex environment or with larger data sets. Accordingly it would be better to store `v`and `f` together in a `data.frame` and than perform on this `data.frame` all kinds of queries and transformations:

```
mdf <- data.frame( v = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), f = factor(rep(c("Drug","Placebo"),5)) )
mdf
    v       f
1   1    Drug
2   2 Placebo
3   3    Drug
4   4 Placebo
...
```

If you want to look at your data interactively, you can subset using the `subset` function:

```
subset( mdf, f == "Drug", select=v )
```

If you are doing this programmatically, you should rather use

```
mdf[ mdf$f == "Drug", "v" ]
```

For the difference of the two have a look at: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset).